# How to change options of existing Fancybox instance?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to change options of a Fancybox instance, after it has opened, outside of its own callbacks.

Specifically, I want to disable the option `closeClick`, after a button has been clicked inside the popup.

This button triggers a function that may take a few seconds to complete, so I want to **disable and re-enable** the `closeClick` option, respectively at the start and end of said function.

Fancybox instance:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    wrapCSS        : 'myPopupClass',
    href           : '#myPopupHTML',
    autoScale      : false,
    autoDimensions : false,
    padding        : 0,
    autoWidth      : true,
    arrows         : false,
    closeBtn       : false,
    scrollOutside  : true,
    openSpeed      : 0,
    closeSpeed     : 0,
    openEffect     : 'none',
    closeEffect    : 'none',
    helpers        :
    {
        overlay :
        {
            css :
            {
                'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
            },
            locked : false
        }
    }
});
```

Change `closeClick` option elsewhere, like such:

```
$('.myPopupClass').fancybox({
    helpers :
    {
        overlay :
        {
            closeClick: false
        }
    }
});
```

It also needs to be done in different scripts, with the following loading order:

```
<script src="preventCloseClick.js"></script>   // Toggle CloseClick in this file
<script src="popup.js"></script>   // Initialize popup in this file
```

The reason for this is that the first file is on every page (where I need my popup functions as well), whereas the second file is only on one specific page.

I might have to put it all in one file, I guess?

---

**Update:** As [suggested by JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281793/how-to-change-options-of-existing-fancybox-instance?noredirect=1#comment39530961_25281793), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348638/how-to-change-fancybox-2-options-on-the-fly/25354285#25354285) solved my problem!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25354285/1055987 if that helps

Comment: @JFK Thanks! That seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
$('.myPopupClass').on('beforeClose', function (oEvent) {
    oEvent.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This might cancel the closing routine, according to line no. 403 here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js

After that you can bind your own click handler to fancy-box close button and cancel the event.

```
function blockClicks(oEvent) {
    oEvent.stopImmidiatePropagation();
    oEvent.preventDefault();
}

$('<close button selector>').on('click', blockClicks);
```

Then trigger your heavy processing, as soon it is done - remove the click blocker

```
$('<close button selector>').off('click', blockClicks);
```

And trigger fancy box close via API:

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

I haven't tested all code snippets above, but they might give you an idea about how to approach your issue.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Also, see my updated question regarding the script files.