# How to change FancyBox 2 options on the fly?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a FancyBox 2.1.5 and it's using overlay "closeClick: true", meaning that FancyBox will close when the overlay is clicked anywhere. I'm updating the FancyBox content dynamically in various ways and would like to be able to change the overlay closeClick behaviour to "false" in a certain scenario.

Is there a way to update FancyBox options dynamically in this way? This change in behavior would not be relatable to any of the ready events/callbacks but would be user-initiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the `closeClick` behavior of the current fancybox once it has been opened; you could only evaluate a condition within the `beforeLoad` or `afterLoad` callbacks and change the API options using `jQuery.extend()` though.

However, as a workaround, you could simulate the API settings and catch `click` events on the overlay to decide whether to close fancybox or not for user-initiated changes so

```
var _closeClick = true; // to simulate overlay closeClick default settings
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // it's important ro revert default settings so we can catch click events
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                closeClick: false // default is true
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            // simulate _closeClick default value
            _closeClick = true;

        },
        // once fancybox is opened, listen for user-initiated changes
        afterShow: function () {
            // button that simulates user-initiated event
            // toggle overlay closeClick on/off on button click
            $("#closeclick").on("click", function (e) {
                _closeClick = _closeClick ? false : true;
                // log changes (debugging)
                var _html = "set overlay closeClick to " + (_closeClick ? false : true) + "";
                $(this).html(_html);
                $("#inline").append("<span id='temp' style='display:block' />");
                $("#temp").html("Current overlay closeClick = " + _closeClick);
                // avoid further click propagation from parent (the overlay perhaps)
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            // bind a click event to overlay
            $(".fancybox-overlay").on("click", function () {
                // if flag is set to true, close fancybox
                if (_closeClick) {
                    $.fancybox.close();
                };
            });
            $(".fancybox-wrap").on("click", function (event) {
                // stopPropagation on children coming from overlay, including #closeclick
                event.stopPropagation();
            });            
        },
        beforeClose: function () {
            // restore settings
            $("#temp").remove();
            $(".fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-wrap").unbind("click");
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq78gua0/)**